# consider a uniformly continuous $f:(a,b) to R$, prove $\lim$ at b exists

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I choose $x_n$ to be a cauchy sequence in (a,b). Then, for $n, m \geq N$, $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$. Since f is uniformly continuous, then $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$ gives f is cauchy. But I don't know how to go further.

Comment: Well, why do you choose a cauchy sequence to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

- Choose $x_n$ to be a sequence converging to $b$.
- $(x_n)$ is therefore a Cauchy sequence
- Your work shows that $(f(x_n))$ is also a Cauchy sequence.
- Therefore...

Comment: how does $x_n$ converging to b give that $x_n$ is cauchy?

Comment: after I show $f(x_n)$ is a cauchy sequence, how can I prove the limit exists?

Comment: @ShuqingJin 1. A convergent sequence is always Cauchy. 2. A Cauchy sequence is convergent in a complete metric space. $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space.